# Как получить элемент, по которому кликнули (js)?

Tags: javascript

Допустим имеется некая страница, на странице имеется множество ссылок/кнопок с разным назначением. Id элементам не задается, классы у всех +/- одинаковые. Как правильно получить элемент, по которому произошел клик?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Свойство `target` ссылается на элемент который вызвал событие

```js
document.addEventListener('click',e => console.log(e.target))
```

```html
<p>p</p><span>span</span><button>button</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Это называется делегирование событий, когда вместо того что бы назначать обработчик на много элементов, мы назначаем один обработчик на родительский элемент  и через свойство события e.target узнаём по какому элементу произошёл клик